# Drag Imageview on the correct touchposition

Tags: java, android, ios, math, canvas

its normally simple math but i dont find the right solution. First of all i have a touch listener that drag and drop the imageview that called sticker in my case. Then when the user hold his finger at least 1 second on the sticker then the drag modus is started and the user can drag the imageview.

unfortunately, i use for now the middle of the sticker for the placement but i want the true touch for the position of the imageview.

Thats my handle of the touchevent

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v instanceof Sticker) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onTouch()");
        Sticker sticker = (Sticker) v;
        Log.i("Sticker"," Found "+sticker.isFound());
        Log.i("Sticker"," Found "+sticker.moving);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("Sticker", " Found moving");
                handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, LONGPRESS_TIME);
                //Take time for the short click
                tslong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

                if(sticker.isFound()) {
                    //Get X,Y for the threshold
                    mDownX = event.getX();
                    mDownY = event.getY();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.i("Sticker"," Found moving");
                if(sticker.isFound()) {
                    if (sticker.moving) {
                        if (Math.abs(mDownX - event.getX()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD || Math.abs(mDownY - event.getY()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD)
                            handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);

                        sticker.coodinates.x = event.getRawX() - sticker.getWidth() / 2;
                        sticker.coodinates.y = event.getRawY() - sticker.getHeight() * 2 / 3;

                        if (sticker.coodinates.x > (layoutSizeWidth * 0.99) - sticker.getWidth()) {
                            sticker.coodinates.x = (float) ((layoutSizeWidth * 0.99)- sticker.getWidth());
                        } else if (sticker.coodinates.x < 0) {
                            sticker.coodinates.x = 1;
                        }

                        if (sticker.coodinates.y > layoutSizeHeight - (sticker.getHeight() * 2 / 2)) {
                            sticker.coodinates.y = layoutSizeHeight - (sticker.getHeight() * 2 / 2);
                        } else if (sticker.coodinates.y < 0) {
                            sticker.coodinates.y = 1;
                        }
                        sticker.setX(sticker.coodinates.x);
                        sticker.setY(sticker.coodinates.y);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) - tslong < INVOKE_POPUP_TIME)
                    handleSimpleClick(v, event);

                if(sticker.isFound()) {
                    if (sticker.moving) {
                        sticker.setX(sticker.coodinates.x);
                        sticker.setY(sticker.coodinates.y);
                        mDownX = event.getX();
                        mDownY = event.getY();
                        sticker.moving = false;
                    }
                    handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here I set the position of the sticker when the user is touched the sticker for 1 second.

```
sticker.coodinates.x = event.getRawX() - sticker.getWidth() / 2;
sticker.coodinates.y = event.getRawY() - sticker.getHeight() * 2 / 3;
```

[image]

Here is a gif for a better understanding:
[enter link description here](https://gfycat.com/AltruisticElasticGilamonster)

As you look closely you see a jump to the touchinput. But the sticker shall be dragable on the touchposition. Hard to say in english :D i cant even explain it in my mother tongue.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: That the sticker(Imageview) is at the correct position. When you look at the top picture. On the left side you see that my program translate the imageview always to the middle of the finger. And at the right picture the position of the sticker is the same like of the touchposition.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. Finally, I found the mistakes. First of all, I have to save the gap between X and the Y coordinate. After that I change the current output of the touch event minus my calculation before the Motion event switch to Action_Move.

Here code of the case Action_Down:

```
getLocationInWindow(startingPointOfImage);
gapX = (int)(event.getRawX()-startingPointOfImage[0]);
gapY = (int)(event.getRawY()-startingPointOfImage[1]);
```

And now i get the input of the event and take minus to them with my calculation of the gap.

```
sticker.coodinates.x = event.getRawX()-gapX;
sticker.coodinates.y = event.getRawY()-gapY;
```

and ending with setting the current X and Y value to the imageview

```
sticker.setX(sticker.coodinates.x);
sticker.setY(sticker.coodinates.y);
```